# Facebook website app in infinite loop when I remove the cookie: true param from FB.init

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Probably a dumb thing to ask, but this will really help me get my head around FB integration.

I am using standard FB.init to use javascript SDK, and using PHP SDK to do some basic API calls:

```
    FB.init({
  appId      : '265236093556723', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
 // cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session. WHY IS THERE AN INFINITE LOOP WHEN THIS IS REMOVED?!?!?!?!?!
  xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
  oauth      : true,
  channelUrl : 'http://www.loveweber.co.uk/dev/fbchannel.php' // Channel File

});
```

I was testing stuff and commented out the cookie: true line. This caused the site to loop through realoding the page and im not sure why. I read everywhere that PHP uses this cookie set by Javascript... so is it something to do with the PHP call to the API?

Or maybe something to do with:

```
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload(); // When user logs in, the page refreshes...
        });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
```

the realoding of the page when a user logs in or out?

Thanks would help such a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.reload(); // When user logs in, the page refreshes...
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
});
```

I notice that your not checking the response variable in either event subscription.  You should ensure that the response is what you think it is before you blindly do the reload();  The reason Facebook sends you the response object is because it is not always what you think.

The response object will be like:

```
     {
       status: "xxx",         /* Current status of the session */
       authResponse: {          /* Information about the current session */
          userID: ""          /* String representing the current user's ID */
          signedRequest: "",  /* String with the current signedRequest */
          expiresIn: "",      /* UNIX time when the session expires */
          accessToken: "",    /* Access token of the user */
       }
     }
```

So be sure the response.status is 'connected' when you subscribe to auth.login. and then not 'connected' when you subscribe to the auth.logout.